# Timepicker cut off on phone

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a very basic alarm clock in Android. The timepicker is for some reason cut off in the middle when I build and load on my phone.

I've tried changing the height in the xml, setting the height as a value, as well as wrap_content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="294dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/artist_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Enter Artist" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/song_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Song or Album"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qAhw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using margins the wrong way.
Delete all the margins and take a look at [RelativeLayout Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative).

Comment: Ah, removing the margin from the timepicker made it work. Thanks.

Comment: @DarrenW Great :)